# Getting TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not callable while asking for user input

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library, user-input

I'm trying to convert an image by removing background and then asking user if they want to resize before saving.
When trying to read user input before saving the file, i get an error: TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not callable. I'm unable to understand how the call to input() is being considered as calling JpegImageFile object. I've only included the working code and not the input() call.

```
from PIL import Image

input_path = 'seal.jpeg'
output_path = 'output.png'

# Open the input image
input_image = Image.open(input_path)

if input_image.mode == 'RGBA':
    # If the image is already transparent, do nothing
    print("Image is already transparent")
else:
    # Convert to RGBA mode to have alpha channel
    rgba = input_image.convert('RGBA')

    # Create a new transparent image with same size
    output_image = Image.new('RGBA', rgba.size, (0,0,0,0))

    # Loop through all the pixels
    for x in range(rgba.size[0]):
        for y in range(rgba.size[1]):
            # Get the RGBA values of the pixel
            r,g,b,a = rgba.getpixel((x,y))
            # Check if the pixel is not too bright (not white or near white)
            if sum((r,g,b)) < 600:
                # Set the pixel in the output image with the same color and alpha value
                output_image.putpixel((x,y), (r,g,b,a))

    # Ask user if they want to resize the output image
    resize_str = "Output image is {}x{} pixels. Do you want to resize it? (y/n): ".format(output_image.size[0], output_image.size[1])
    resize_choice = input("{}".format(resize_str))
    if resize_choice.lower() == "y":
        percent_str = "Enter desired resize percentage (e.g. 50 for 50%): "
        resize_percent = int(input("{}".format(percent_str)))
        resize = (int(output_image.size[0]*resize_percent/100), int(output_image.size[1]*resize_percent/100))
        output_image = output_image.resize(resize)

    # Save the output image
    output_image.save(output_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Created another function to take user input and called it from within the above code which worked.